# Why is $|x| = -x$ in $\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{3-x}{\sqrt{2x^2-1}}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I have a few limits to infinity examples like this:

> $$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{3-x}{\sqrt{2x^2-1}}$$
>
> Grab the elements with highest exponent.
>
> $$\frac{-x}{\sqrt{2x^2}}$$
>
> Then
>
> $$\frac{-x}{\sqrt{2} \cdot \sqrt{x^2}}$$
>
> Note that $\sqrt{x^2}$ is $|x|$ and not $x$:
>
> $$\frac{-x}{\sqrt{2} \cdot|x|}$$
>
> It follows that
>
> $$\frac{-x}{\sqrt{2} \cdot (-x)}$$
>
> So the limit is
>
> $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

---

I don't understand the penultimate step: how did $|x|$ become $-x$?

Comment: Where did you get this solution?

Comment: @Aleksandar Eh, I copied it from the lecture but I don't quite remember the reasoning behind it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall the definition of $|x|$: it is $x$ if $x\ge0$ and $-x$ otherwise. Since we are taking the limit as $x\to-\infty$, we can assume $x<0$ and so $|x|=-x$.